# CSS Button, default color, hover color and :active color change

Tags: html, css, asp.net, hover

first of all there is my button's code;

## HTML

```
<asp:Button Text="Register" ForeColor="#ffffff" BackColor=" #ba04c2" ID="btnReg" CssClass="btnReg" runat="server" OnClick="btnReg_Click" />
```

## CSS

```
.left-side .fast-reg .alt .btnReg{
 width: 100px;
 height: 40px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 line-height: 40px;
 text-align: center;
 float: right;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; 
 transition-duration: 0.4s;

}
.btnReg:hover {
    background-color: #d053f5; 
    
}

.btnReg:focus {
    background-color: #3e0442; 
    
}
```

I want to change the default color for my button, hover color and when it is pressed.

For example, the color of the button is purple, when cursor will appear on the button and the color will become clear. When the button gets clicked, the color will be more darker.

I put `BackColor="#colorcode"` to asp:button part, but when I do that, hover is being deactivated.

How can I change the button color while `hover` and `:active` function is not being deactivated?

Comment: Don't give background color in your asp code. Instead give it in your CSS. Then it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the `BackColor` property of an `asp:Button` it actually gets rendered in HTML like this:

```
<input type="button" style="background-color: #ba04c2; ..." />
```

The `style` attribute that you see in foregoing `input` element is called **inline styling**. And most of the cases inline styling automatically wins over CSS definitions because of the "*[CSS Specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)*". In CSS world every styling has its own weight and they are applied to an element respectively to that weight.

So, if you want to override an inline style in your CSS you have to force it by adding `!important` to your CSS definition as follows.

```
.btnReg:hover {
    background-color: #d053f5 !important; 
}
```